# Is there anyway to extend an UITableViewController onto an UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

First off I'm quite new to objective-c and xcode in general, so it prop just a lack of fundamental knowledge.

But basically need to extend an `UITableViewController` onto an `UIViewController`
or to but in another way i need an interface (header) that inherits the implementation from my `UIViewController` but is an `UITableViewController`

To achieve this I would have done something like this in C#:

```
@interface Keyboard_Field_Extensions_UIViewController : UIViewController 
@end

@interface Keyboard_Field_Extensions_UITableViewController : Keyboard_Field_Extensions_UIViewController, UITableViewController
@end
```

Is there any way around doing this in `objective-c`? Maybe using delegates? But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective C doesn't have multiple inheritance, like C++ or C#
UITableViewController doesn't need to be extended to UIViewController because it's ALREADY a UIViewController(extended by some methods for working with tableview)

It's inheritance chain -UITableViewController: UIViewController : UIResponder : NSObject

Comment: It is? Awsome.. thnx alot.. knew it was a simpel lack of fundamental knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no multiple inheritance within objective-c. Delegates or protocols respectively may be an option or extending an existing class without implementing a subclass. (quite unique to objective-C if I am not much mistaken)

However, in general it may not be a good idea to extend or subclass UITableView, although it can be done. You should describe a bit more in detail what you want to achieve on the UI. Then you may get much better suggestions than this general "you can use a protocol/delegate".